# Scheme, SICP, R5RS, why is delay not a special form?

Tags: scheme, sicp, r5rs

This is concerning chapter 3.5 from SICP, in which streams are being discussed. The idea is that:

```
(cons-stream 1 (display 'hey))
```

Should not evaluate the second part of the cons-stream, so it should not print “hey”. This does happen, I get the following output:

*hey(1 . #< promise >)*

So my conclusion is that delay is not implemented as a special form? Or am I doing something wrong? I use the following implementation:

```
(define (cons-stream a b) 
  (cons a (delay b)))
```

With delay being the default R5RS implementation. Is this a fault in the implementation, or am I not doing or understanding it right?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You *do* create a promise, but the promise is created inside your `cons-stream`, which means that it's too late and the expression was already evaluated.  Try this:

```
(define (foo x)
  (display "foo: ") (write x) (newline)
  x)

(cons-stream 1 (foo 2))
```

and you'll see that it's evaluated too early.  For the same reason, this:

```
(define ones (cons-stream 1 ones))
```

and any other infinite list won't work when your `cons-stream` is a function.  So the thing is that `delay` is a special form, but you're not using its feature since you define `cons-stream` as a plain function.  You have to define `cons-stream` as a macro if you want to make *it* behave in the same special way too.  For example:

```
(define-syntax cons-stream
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(cons-stream x y) (cons x (delay y))]))
```

Comment: Thanks! But how would I create a cons-stream that would work the way it does in the book?