# what's wrong with this define-syntax macro in scheme?

Tags: macros, scheme, guile, define-syntax

I'm working though SICP and wanted to try out some of the examples in guile. I'm trying the stream examples and wanted an implementation for cons-stream, which I got from [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5610480/scheme-sicp-r5rs-why-is-delay-not-a-special-form/5610512#5610512). However when I type this into guile I get:

```
guile> (define-syntax cons-stream
  (syntax-rules ()
  [(cons-stream x y) (cons x (delay y))]))
ERROR: invalid syntax ()
ABORT: (misc-error)
```

I have no idea what's wrong with this - I've tried replacing () with '(), removing the [ ], but it still doesn't work even though it seems to be [valid R5RS](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-2.html#%_toc_%_sec_4.3.2). I'm currently on guile 1.8.7, I can't see a package for v2.0.1 which the [GNU docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/index.html) mention, could this be why its not working for me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you need to import support for `syntax-rules` first (see http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/docs/docs-1.8/guile-ref/Syntax-Rules.html):

```
(use-syntax (ice-9 syncase))
```

Then you need to change the square brackets to parens; after that it should work.

Definitely don't quote the literals list; that's a sequence of identifiers, like `lambda` formals, not an expression.