# How is delay implemented?

Tags: stream, scheme, lazy-evaluation, sicp

I have a firm understanding of how lazy evaluation and streams work.

However I'm having some trouble simply following the book at this point. I don't really undrestand what it is trying to tell me about `delay`, and here is why.

At page 321 it reads

> `Cons-stream` is a special form defined so that
>
> ```scm
> (cons-stream 〈a〉 〈b〉)
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```scm
> (cons 〈a〉 (delay 〈b〉))
> ```

and a related footnote

> […] If `cons-stream` were a procedure, then […] evaluating `(cons-stream 〈a〉 〈b〉)` would automatically cause `〈b〉` to be evaluated, which is precisely what we do not want to happen. For the same reason, `delay` must be a special form […]

So I conclude that I *can't* implement `cons-stream` nor `delay`, at least not with the tools I have been given at this stage in the book, so I don't understand what the quote above is trying to tell me, beside "it's kinda this, but not quite".

Later, though, there's a "section" of the book titled

#### Implementing `delay` and `force`

Which says something similar to before:

> `Delay` can be a special form such that
>
> ```scm
> (delay 〈exp〉)
> ```
>
> is syntactic sugar for
>
> ```scm
> (lambda () 〈exp〉)
> ```

But again, how do I define `delay` if I don't know how to define a special form?

Paradoxically, immediately after one finds that

> This implementation suffices for `delay` and `force` to work as advertised, but […]

(and the "but" has nothing to do with special forms but just with performance), but how can it work if it's not a special form, defined like this?

And even if I wanted to assume that `delay` is already defined in whatever Scheme interpreter I'm using (which is the case [for this online compiler](https://rextester.com/l/common_lisp_online_compiler)), I would still be unable to define a special form that makes use of it, such as `cons-stream`.

Bottom line, I don't know how to write anything for making the exercises.

Eventually, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5610512/5825294) showing how to define a special form, but the point is that the `define-syntax` used therein is not even mentioned in the whole book.

So how was I supposed to do the exercises?

Comment: Is `lambda` a special form?

Comment: To define your own special forms you need to use macros. SICP doesn't teach about macros, that's why you can't find it in the book. You just have to take it as given that the special form exists.

Comment: Remember, SICP is not intended to teach all of the Scheme language. It's a textbook on programming principles. It omits features that aren't important for its pedagogic approach.

Comment: @Barmar, maybe implementing `delay` is not important pedagogically, but doing the exercises is. And I can't do the exercises on streams if I don't have either of `delay` and `cons-stream`. I guess the point is that [the online compiler](https://rextester.com/l/scheme_online_compiler) I linked is just not sufficient for that, as it doesn't have `const-stream`? (Well, as long as I don't use `define-syntax` as described.)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260685/what-is-the-best-scheme-implementation-for-working-through-sicp

Comment: `delay` and `force` have been standard scheme since at least R3RS...

Comment: And even that old version of guile you're using supports streams but you have to load the appropriate module first with `(use-modules (srfi srfi-41))`

Comment: (you're better off installing a scheme system locally than trying to use some online repl though)

Answer (score 2):

You were supposed to just write the code explicitly according to the syntactical definitions, either as

```
   (cons A (delay B))
```

or

```
   (cons A (lambda () B))
```

or even

```
   (cons A (memo (lambda () B)))
```

instead of

```
   (cons-stream A B)
```

everywhere. It's not that bad. I did it once or twice, too. `memo` can even be defined as a function pretty straightforwardly.

In fact, this is how the text can plausibly be interpreted anyway. It is saying to you, ***if** `delay` and `stream-cons` were defined, then writing **`this`** would be exactly the same as writing **`that`*** .... well then, just go head and write *`that`* in the first place!

---

The longer way is to define your own interpreter, and have *it* handle those additional *special forms* - not "macros" - for you as needed.

You would write your programs as quoted lists, and use them as an input to the interpreter.

You can also fake it by doing whole program transformations, writing new source files out, and loading *these* transformed source files back with the same interpreter you're already using.

---

An intermediate way is to define your streams as stateful objects with explicit pull requests etc., have the constructor store the lambda function(s) inside, and build the rest on top of that.

Trying to define e.g. Hamming sequence with this kind of streams is actually an interesting exercise, forces you to deal with various issues explicitly that might otherwise remain implicit.

Comment: ... this reminds me of Clojure's macros.

Answer (score 2):

The way you were were supposed to do the exercises was by using the implementation of the language that the authors of the book intended you to use, rather than some other one which has a different set of features.  That implementation is, I presume, [MIT Scheme](https://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/projects/scheme/).

Sorry to be so blunt, but it is unreasonable to expect that the authors of SICP should have written it in such a way that it is possible to use the book directly for any number of a wide variety of implementations of differing versions of Scheme.  People who use such implementations (which is fine) are inevitably going to run into some places where what SICP talks about requires some work to support.  This is one.

However, what they do say is that, if you simply manually replace every occurrence of `(cons-stream a b)` by `(cons a (delay b))` and every occurrence of `(delay x)` by `(lambda () x)` and then define `force`: `(define (force p) (p))` then things will work, with some caveats.

They are not expecting you to actually have to do this, because they're expecting you to be using an implementation where these things are defined by the implementation.  But you could.

---

Of course, pretty soon you discover that if you take a program which makes use of, say, `cons-stream` then you could (a) notice that the *source* of that program is expressed as something which is equivalent to a Scheme data structure, and (b) therefore write a program, in Scheme, which would mechanically turn that source into the source of another program which did not use `cons-stream`, by making the substitutions they suggest.  And you can do the same thing for `delay`.  (There is no need to do the same for `force` however: why?)

Well, the idea of writing such program-transforming programs is something that happened [pretty early in the history of Lisp-family languages](https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/6111).  Getting such a thing really correct is fairly painful however, and there has been a great deal of history and argument around this.

But in [modern](https://small.r7rs.org/) Scheme there is an interface to this program-transforming process which lets you define things like `cons-stream`:

```
(define-syntax delay
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ form)
     (lambda () form))))

(define (force p)
  ;; Assumption: force is only ever called on promises!
  (p))

(define-syntax cons-stream
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ a b)
     (cons a (delay b)))))
```

Or you could feel your oats and write

```
(define-syntax delay
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ form)
     (let ((v #f) (forced #f))
       (lambda ()
         (if forced
             v
             (begin
               (set! v form)
               (set! forced #t)
               v)))))))
```

Comment: side note: that's [AIM-057](https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/6111), "MACRO Definitions for LISP" by Timothy P. Hart, 1963-10-01.